# How to style Chakra UI toast - with color - with chakra-ui/react 2.4.2 and next v13

Tags: css, reactjs, chakra-ui

I am trying to figure out how to add color and backgroundColor styles to my Chakra UI toast.

I have a toast component:

```
import type { UseToastOptions } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import { useToast as useChakraToast } from "@chakra-ui/react"

export function useToast() {
  const toast = useChakraToast()
  const handleToast = (props: UseToastOptions) => {
    toast({
      position: "bottom-right",
      isClosable: true,
      status: "success",

      ...props,
    })
  }
  return handleToast
}
```

I also have an attempt to use it, which works, but I can't add color styles:

```
import { useApolloClient } from "@apollo/client"
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

import { useToast } from "./useToast"

export const useLogout = () => {
  const client = useApolloClient()
  const router = useRouter()
  const toast = useToast()
  const handleLogout = async () => {
    await router.replace("/logout")
    await fetch("/api/logout", { method: "post" })
    await client.resetStore()
    toast({ description: "Successfully logged out!" } )
  }
  return handleLogout
}
```

I'd like to find a way to make success equal
color: "brand.white" and bg: "brand.green" in the useToast component - but it wont accept those values.  I also cant add them in the logout toast.

Where can I put them?

I tried adding properties to my theme.tsx as follows:

```
components: {
    Button,
    Input,
    Select,
    Textarea,
    // I tried Alert and ToastOptions instead of Toast, but it doesn't make any difference 
    Toast: {
      baseStyle: {},
      defaultProps: {},
      variants: {
        // I tried sprinkling this everywhere - it doesn't make any difference
        background: "unset",
        solid: {
        background: "unset",
        success: {
          background: "unset",
          bg: "brand.green",
          color: "brand.white",
        },
        error: {
          bg: "brand.red",
          color: "brand.white",
        },
        info: {
          bg: "brand.blue",
          color: "brand.white",
        }

      },
      },
    },
```

but they aren't being observed by the toast component. I also tried changing the component header from Toast to each of Alert and ToastOptions, but neither of those attempts work either.

Noting [this page of the chakra UI docs](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/alert/theming), I tried to make a custom component for alert styles as follows:

```
import { alertAnatomy } from '@chakra-ui/anatomy'
import { createMultiStyleConfigHelpers } from '@chakra-ui/react'


const { definePartsStyle, defineMultiStyleConfig } =
  createMultiStyleConfigHelpers(alertAnatomy.keys)

const baseStyle = definePartsStyle({
  // define the part you're going to style
        variants: {
            solid: {
            background: "unset",
            success: {
                background: "unset",
                bg: "brand.green",
                color: "brand.white",
            },
            error: {
                background: "unset",
                bg: "brand.tomato",
                color: "brand.white",
            },
            info: {
                background: "unset",
                bg: "brand.blue",
                color: "brand.sludge",
            }
        }  
      

  },
})

export const alertTheme = defineMultiStyleConfig({ baseStyle })
```

VSCode is telling me that:

> Module '"@chakra-ui/react"' has no exported member
> 'createMultiStyleConfigHelpers'

I am using the  "@chakra-ui/react": "2.4.4", and cannot get the method shown in the chakra ui docs to work.

**Next attempt:**

I have seen [this post](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/7170) reporting issues with next v13. I tried pinning to v2.4.4 and 2.4.2. Currently, I'm on 2.4.2 (there seems to be a compatibility issue with 2.4.4).

When I try making an alert.ts file with shades of green background for success and red for error (defined as brand colors in my extendTheme) as follows:

```
import { alertAnatomy } from '@chakra-ui/anatomy';
import {
  createMultiStyleConfigHelpers,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';

const { definePartsStyle, defineMultiStyleConfig } =
  createMultiStyleConfigHelpers(alertAnatomy.keys);

//  Defining styles for the first custom variant
const customSuccess = definePartsStyle({
  container: {
    border: '1px solid',
    borderColor: 'brand.green',
    background: 'brand.green',
    
    _dark: {
      borderColor: 'brand.green',
      background: 'brand.green',
      
    },
  },
  title: {
    color: 'brand.white',
    _dark: {
      color: 'brand.white',
    },
  },
  description: {
    color: 'brand.white',
    _dark: {
      color: 'brand.white',
    },
  },
});

//  Defining styles for the second custom variant
const customError = definePartsStyle({
  container: {
    border: '1px solid',
    borderColor: 'brand.tomato',
    background: 'brand.tomato',
    _dark: {
      borderColor: 'brand.tomato',
      background: 'brand.tomato',
    },
  },
  title: {
    color: 'brand.white',
    _dark: {
      color: 'brand.white',
    },
  },
  description: {
    color: 'brand.white',
    _dark: {
      color: 'brand.white',
    },
  },
});

const alertTheme = defineMultiStyleConfig({
  variants: { customSuccess, customError },
});

export default alertTheme
```

I then import it in my extendTheme and try and use it in my toast as follows:

```
{
            onSuccess: async () => {
              await fetch("api/issue", { method: "delete" }),
                toast({
                  title: "deleted",
                  description: "Your entry has been deleted",
                  status: "success",
                  variant: "customSuccess"
                })
    
              refetchAllIssueGroups()
            },
          },
```

When I try this, I get a white background with black text. I get the same black and white regardless of success or failure.

Is chakra capable of using brand colors in alerts?

My useToastOptions.ts file has:

```
import { AlertProps, AlertStatus } from '@chakra-ui/alert';
import { SystemStyleObject, ThemingProps, StyleProps, useChakra, ColorMode } from '@chakra-ui/system';
import * as react from 'react';
import { Variants } from 'framer-motion';
import { PortalProps } from '@chakra-ui/portal';

declare type LogicalToastPosition = "top-start" | "top-end" | "bottom-start" | "bottom-end";
declare type ToastPositionWithLogical = LogicalToastPosition | "top" | "top-left" | "top-right" | "bottom" | "bottom-left" | "bottom-right";
declare type ToastPosition = Exclude<ToastPositionWithLogical, LogicalToastPosition>;
declare function getToastPlacement(position: ToastPosition | undefined, dir: "ltr" | "rtl"): ToastPosition | undefined;

interface RenderProps extends UseToastOptions {
    /**
     * Function to close the toast
     */
    onClose(): void;
}
declare type ToastMessage = (props: RenderProps) => React.ReactNode;
declare type ToastId = string | number;
interface ToastOptions {
    /**
     * The element or component type to render.
     * The component will be passed `id` and `onClose`
     */
    message: ToastMessage;
    /**
     * The toast's id
     */
    id: ToastId;
    /**
     * The duration of the toast
     */
    duration: number | null;
    /**
     * The status of the toast's alert component.
     */
    status: Status;
    /**
     * Function that removes the toast from manager's state.
     */
    onRequestRemove(): void;
    /**
     * The position of the toast
     */
    position: ToastPosition;
    /**
     * Callback function to run side effects after the toast has closed.
     */
    onCloseComplete?(): void;
    /**
     * Internally used to queue closing a toast. Should probably not be used by
     * anyone else, but documented regardless.
     */
    requestClose?: boolean;
    /**
     * Optional style overrides for the toast component.
     */
    containerStyle?: SystemStyleObject;
}
declare type ToastState = {
    [K in ToastPosition]: ToastOptions[];
};
declare type Status = "default" | "success" | "error" | "warning" | "info" | "loading";
declare type UpdateFn = (state: ToastState) => void;
declare type CloseAllToastsOptions = {
    positions?: ToastPosition[];
};

interface ToastProps extends UseToastOptions, Omit<AlertProps, keyof UseToastOptions> {
    onClose?: () => void;
}
/**
 * The `Toast` component is used to give feedback to users after an action has taken place.
 *
 * @see Docs https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/toast
 */
declare const Toast: React.FC<ToastProps>;
declare function createRenderToast(options?: UseToastOptions & {
    toastComponent?: React.FC<ToastProps>;
}): react.FC<RenderProps>;
declare type UseToastPromiseOption = Omit<UseToastOptions, "status">;
declare function createToastFn(dir: "ltr" | "rtl", defaultOptions?: UseToastOptions): {
    (options?: UseToastOptions): ToastId;
    update(id: ToastId, options: Omit<UseToastOptions, "id">): void;
    promise<Result extends unknown, Err extends Error = Error>(promise: Promise<Result>, options: {
        success: MaybeFunction<UseToastPromiseOption, [Result]>;
        error: MaybeFunction<UseToastPromiseOption, [Err]>;
        loading: UseToastPromiseOption;
    }): void;
    closeAll: (options?: CloseAllToastsOptions | undefined) => void;
    close: (id: ToastId) => void;
    isActive: (id: ToastId) => boolean;
};
declare type CreateToastFnReturn = ReturnType<typeof createToastFn>;
declare type MaybeFunction<T, Args extends unknown[] = []> = T | ((...args: Args) => T);

interface UseToastOptions extends ThemingProps<"Alert"> {
    /**
     * The placement of the toast
     *
     * @default "bottom"
     */
    position?: ToastPosition;
    /**
     * The delay before the toast hides (in milliseconds)
     * If set to `null`, toast will never dismiss.
     *
     * @default 5000 ( = 5000ms )
     */
    duration?: ToastOptions["duration"];
    /**
     * Render a component toast component.
     * Any component passed will receive 2 props: `id` and `onClose`.
     */
    render?(props: RenderProps): React.ReactNode;
    /**
     * The title of the toast
     */
    title?: React.ReactNode;
    /**
     * The description of the toast
     */
    description?: React.ReactNode;
    /**
     * If `true`, toast will show a close button
     */
    isClosable?: boolean;
    /**
     * The status of the toast.
     */
    status?: AlertStatus;
    /**
     * A custom icon that will be displayed by the toast.
     */
    icon?: React.ReactNode;
    /**
     * The `id` of the toast.
     *
     * Mostly used when you need to prevent duplicate.
     * By default, we generate a unique `id` for each toast
     */
    id?: ToastId;
    /**
     * Callback function to run side effects after the toast has closed.
     */
    onCloseComplete?: () => void;
    /**
     * Optional style overrides for the container wrapping the toast component.
     */
    containerStyle?: StyleProps;
}
/**
 * React hook used to create a function that can be used
 * to show toasts in an application.
 */
declare function useToast(defaultOptions?: UseToastOptions): CreateToastFnReturn;

interface ToastComponentProps extends ToastOptions, Pick<ToastProviderProps, "motionVariants" | "toastSpacing"> {
}

interface ToastMethods {
    /**
     * Function to actually create a toast and add it
     * to state at the specified position
     */
    notify: (message: ToastMessage, options?: CreateToastOptions) => ToastId;
    /**
     * Close all toasts at once.
     * If given positions, will only close those.
     */
    closeAll: (options?: CloseAllToastsOptions) => void;
    /**
     * Requests to close a toast based on its id and position
     */
    close: (id: ToastId) => void;
    /**
     * Update a specific toast with new options based on the
     * passed `id`
     */
    update: (id: ToastId, options: Omit<UseToastOptions, "id">) => void;
    isActive: (id: ToastId) => boolean;
}
declare type CreateToastOptions = Partial<Pick<ToastOptions, "status" | "duration" | "position" | "id" | "onCloseComplete" | "containerStyle">>;
declare type ToastProviderProps = React.PropsWithChildren<{
    /**
     * Default options for `useToast(options)`
     *
     * @example
     * <ToastProvider defaultOptions={{ duration: 10_000, isClosable: true }} />
     */
    defaultOptions?: UseToastOptions;
    /**
     * Customize the default motion config to animate the toasts your way
     *
     * @example
     * const motionVariants =
     * <ToastProvider motionVariants={motionVariants} />
     */
    motionVariants?: Variants;
    /**
     * Are you looking for a way to style the toast? Use a custom `Alert` variant in the theme.
     * This property overrides the default ToastComponent with your own implementation.
     *
     * @example
     * const CustomToastComponent = (props: ToastComponentProps) => ...
     * <ToastProvider component={CustomToastComponent} />
     *
     * @default ToastComponent
     */
    component?: React.FC<ToastComponentProps>;
    /**
     * Define the margin between toasts
     *
     * @default 0.5rem
     */
    toastSpacing?: string | number;
    /**
     * Props to be forwarded to the portal component
     */
    portalProps?: Pick<PortalProps, "appendToParentPortal" | "containerRef">;
}>;
/**
 * Manages the creation, and removal of toasts
 * across all corners ("top", "bottom", etc.)
 */
declare const ToastProvider: (props: ToastProviderProps) => JSX.Element;

interface CreateStandAloneToastParam extends Partial<ReturnType<typeof useChakra> & {
    setColorMode: (value: ColorMode) => void;
    defaultOptions: UseToastOptions;
}>, Omit<ToastProviderProps, "children"> {
}
declare const defaultStandaloneParam: CreateStandAloneToastParam & Required<Omit<CreateStandAloneToastParam, keyof ToastProviderProps>>;
declare type CreateStandaloneToastReturn = {
    ToastContainer: () => JSX.Element;
    toast: CreateToastFnReturn;
};
/**
 * Create a toast
 */
declare function createStandaloneToast({ theme, colorMode, toggleColorMode, setColorMode, defaultOptions, motionVariants, toastSpacing, component, forced, }?: CreateStandAloneToastParam): CreateStandaloneToastReturn;

export { CloseAllToastsOptions, CreateStandAloneToastParam, CreateStandaloneToastReturn, CreateToastFnReturn, CreateToastOptions, LogicalToastPosition, RenderProps, Status, Toast, ToastId, ToastMessage, ToastMethods, ToastOptions, ToastPosition, ToastPositionWithLogical, ToastProps, ToastProvider, ToastProviderProps, ToastState, UpdateFn, UseToastOptions, createRenderToast, createStandaloneToast, createToastFn, defaultStandaloneParam, getToastPlacement, useToast };
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Chakra UI [document](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/alert/theming), a basic solution would be to create custom variants for `Alert`, which is used internally by `Toast`, so `Toast` can be styled by using the variants.

When tested in a newly installed Chakra UI environment with basic setup, importing `createMultiStyleConfigHelpers` does not seems to have errors occurred.

Here is a simple live demo for the test on: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ex5pw9?file=src/App.js).

First define styles for the custom variants in `theme`:

```
// '@chakra-ui/anatomy' may need to be installed

import { alertAnatomy } from '@chakra-ui/anatomy';
import {
  ChakraProvider,
  extendTheme,
  createMultiStyleConfigHelpers,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';

const { definePartsStyle, defineMultiStyleConfig } =
  createMultiStyleConfigHelpers(alertAnatomy.keys);

//  Defining styles for the first custom variant
const customSuccess = definePartsStyle({
  container: {
    border: '1px solid',
    borderColor: 'teal.200',
    background: 'teal.500',
    _dark: {
      borderColor: 'teal.600',
      background: 'teal.800',
    },
  },
  title: {
    color: 'pink.200',
    _dark: {
      color: 'pink.200',
    },
  },
});

//  Defining styles for the second custom variant
const customError = definePartsStyle({
  container: {
    border: '1px solid',
    borderColor: 'pink.200',
    background: 'pink.400',
    _dark: {
      borderColor: 'pink.600',
      background: 'pink.800',
    },
  },
  title: {
    color: 'teal.200',
    _dark: {
      color: 'teal.300',
    },
  },
});

const alertTheme = defineMultiStyleConfig({
  variants: { customSuccess, customError },
});

export const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Alert: alertTheme,
  },
});
```

Then apply to `useToast`, its `variant` property uses the same variants set for `Alert`:

```
<Button
  colorScheme="teal"
  onClick={() =>
    toast({
      title: "Account created.",
      description: "We've created your account for you.",
      status: "success",
      duration: 9000,
      isClosable: true,
      variant: "customSuccess",
    })
  }
>
  Show success
</Button>
```

```
<Button
  colorScheme="pink"
  onClick={() =>
    toast({
      title: "Account created.",
      description: "We've created your account for you.",
      status: "error",
      duration: 9000,
      isClosable: true,
      variant: "customError",
    })
  }
>
  Show error
</Button>
```

Comment: As I said in my post, I tried using the Chakra UI docs, which you have copied and pasted. As noted, an error is returned saying the create module is not exported from chakra-ui. Perhaps the docs are out of date, the module is no longer supported or something else that stops this solution from working.

Comment: @Mel My bad, I tried in the [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ex5pw9?file=src/App.js) included in the answer with a newly installed Chakra UI environment, it seemed to be working. Perhaps something is different due to versions.

Comment: thanks very much, ill check my versions

Comment: thanks for trying to help @JohnLi. This doesn't work, but adding points to you to say thank you. I'll start a new bounty to keep trying to find some help.

Comment: Thanks anyway for trying to help. I have given up trying to figure out how to work with chakra ui and switched to tailwind

Comment: @Mel Thanks for the reply, too bad a working solution couldn't be found though. I had also suspected if the typescript config could be in conflict with chakra, but in such case, perhaps none of its functions are likely to work, not just with this one. Anyways with no other information to be found after we checked everywhere, I think indeed switching would be right and practical at this point if it's possible in the use case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with styling the Alert component. After some research I managed to do it by changing the component styles in theme.js like so:

```
//_app.js
import { theme } from 'theme';

<ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
//... 
</ChakraProvider >

//theme.js

import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react';

const textStyles = {...}
const colors = {...}

const components = {
  Alert: {
    variants: {
      solid: {
        container: {
          bg: '#fff',
          ...
        },
        title: {
          color: 'brand',
        },
        description: {
          ...
        },
        icon: {
          ...
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

export const theme = extendTheme({ colors, components, textStyles });
```

Comment: How did you give those properties to the toast component? I have brand.green defined in my version of this theme file and am trying to use it to make the background color of my toast

Comment: scratch that - github copilot just suggested a way -testing it now

Comment: I defined the props inside the colors object. But trust the AI it knows everything :D.
Also the other answer here seems like a good way to solve your problem

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried using copilot's suggestion but the toast component doesn't use those values.

Comment: I see what your issue is, you can't access the status prop and so you can't really style it properly. I think the only solution I can think of is to define a custom Alert component as described here https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/alert/theming#showcase. But man it's a lot of work to just change a colour

Comment: Apparently, Charka UI has no exported member 'createMultiStyleConfigHelpers' - which is the import used in the Chakra UI docs to make a custom component

Answer (score 0):

it is more useful to use custom toast in chakra-ui.

```
const toast = useToast()
```

---

```
toast({
      duration: 4000,
      isClosable: true,
      render: () => (
        <CustomToast
          description="Your Description"
          status="success" // "info" | "error"
        />
      ),
    })
```

and custom toast component might use the Alert component of chakra.

```
  <Alert status={status}> {description} </ Alert>
```

Comment: Where can I put the color and background color properties?

Comment: it should take it from status. success-info-error etc.
see alert component of chakra
https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/alert/usage

Comment: Where can I define success?